# Query that combines the contents of 3 columns, but also filters by a date in a 4th column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

This is an example of my data that is located on a sheet called Data:

| Date | Fruit 1 | Fruit 2 | Fruit 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | Apple | Mango | Apple |
| 2/1/2021 | Cherry | Banana | Pear |
| 2/1/2021 | Orange |  |  |
| 1/1/2022 | Apple | Cherry | Orange |
| 2/1/2022 |  |  |  |
| 2/1/2022 | Pear | Banana |  |
| 21/1/2022 | Cherry | Banana |  |

Desired output:

Filtered to only show data between 1/1/2022 and 31/12/2022, sorted by the Count. The start and end dates are located in cells C2 and E2

| Suggestions | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | 2 |
| Cherry | 2 |
| Apple | 1 |
| Orange | 1 |
| Pear | 1 |

I have achieved what I want in 2 steps:

First is a query that filters the data by dates specified and removes any rows that have no data in the 'Fruit 1' column. This formula is located in Cell D5.

```
=QUERY (Data!A:D,"SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE A > date '"&TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B<>''",1)
```

| D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | Apple | Cherry | Orange |
| 2/1/2022 | Pear | Banana |  |
| 21/1/2022 | Cherry | Banana |  |

then running a second query on those results that combines the 'Fruit 1', 'Fruit 2' and 'Fruit 3' columns and returns the data sorted by count as shown in my desired output above.

```
=QUERY({E5:E;F5:F;G5:G}, "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label (Col1) 'Sorted List', count(Col1) 'Count'",1)
```

What I would really like to do is to do this in one query, but I can't find information on how to run a second query on the data that is generated by the first query... or how to approach it.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in a "wide" format, which makes it harder to work with. You may want to **Insert > Sheet** and unpivot the data into a "tall" format, like this:

| Date | Category | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | Fruit 1 | Apple |
| 2020-01-01 | Fruit 2 | Mango |
| 2020-01-01 | Fruit 3 | Apple |
| 2021-01-02 | Fruit 1 | Cherry |
| 2021-01-02 | Fruit 2 | Banana |
| 2021-01-02 | Fruit 3 | Pear |
| 2021-01-02 | Fruit 1 | Orange |
| 2022-01-01 | Fruit 1 | Apple |
| 2022-01-01 | Fruit 2 | Cherry |
| 2022-01-01 | Fruit 3 | Orange |
| 2022-01-02 | Fruit 1 | Pear |
| 2022-01-02 | Fruit 2 | Banana |
| 2022-01-21 | Fruit 1 | Cherry |
| 2022-01-21 | Fruit 2 | Banana |

Once you have that, the report can be created with this `query()` formula:

```
=query( 
  { Data2!A1:C }, 
  "select Col3, count(Col3) 
   where 
     date " & text(C2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " <= toDate(Col1) 
     and toDate(Col1) <= date " & text(E2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   group by Col3 
   order by count(Col3) desc", 
  1 
)
```

If you do not want to insert a helper sheet, you can unpivot and query in one go with this formula:

```
=query( 
  let( 
    table, Data!A1:D, 
    numColsToRepeat, 1, 
    numColsToSqueeze, columns(table) - numColsToRepeat, 
    headers, { offset(table, 0, 0, 1, numColsToRepeat), "Category", "Data" }, 
    categories, offset(table, 0, numColsToRepeat, 1, numColsToSqueeze), 
    colsToRepeat, offset(table, 1, 0, rows(table) - 1, numColsToRepeat), 
    colsToSqueeze, offset(table, 1, numColsToRepeat, rows(table) - 1, numColsToSqueeze), 
    reduce( 
      headers, colsToSqueeze, 
      lambda( 
        result, cell, 
        if( 
          cell = "", 
          result, 
          let( 
            rowIndex, row(cell) - row(colsToSqueeze) + 1, 
            columnIndex, column(cell) - column(colsToSqueeze) + 1, 
            { 
              result; 
              { 
                index(colsToRepeat, rowIndex), 
                index(categories, 1, columnIndex), 
                cell 
              } 
            } 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "select Col3, count(Col3) 
   where 
     date " & text(C2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " <= toDate(Col1) 
     and toDate(Col1) <= date " & text(E2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   group by Col3 
   order by count(Col3) desc", 
  1 
)
```

To unpivot the data into a "tall" format, use the longish `let()` in there, without the query wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should clarify a couple of things, the real world use of this is that the rows are collected in a google form looking for 3 suggestions from respondents. There are currently nearly 3000 rows in the table that I need to extract the kind of query from, and there will only ever be 3 'fruit'.

Does that change the way your solutions work?

Comment: The formula should work just fine with the data you describe.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand what you are suggesting :)  I'll give it a go!

Comment: In my effort to simplify my question, I may have missed some vital info as to the structure /content of the original data sheet... The form collects a lot of information... the date is column J in that sheet, and the data I need to extract here is in columns V,W and X ...

How would I modify your query to select those specific columns?

Comment: **Insert > Sheet** and unpivot to that sheet using `Data!A1:X` and the correct `numColsToRepeat`. Then modify the `query()` so that the [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) points to the columns you want to count.

Comment: Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.